# Error protocol 41 >= NPROTO(41) adding new protocol to linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, sockets, kernel, network-protocols

For studying purpose, I'm developing a new protocol called **HTP** (at transport layer as UDP/TCP) and tend to register it to Linux kernel as a module.

Following this tutorial
https://linuxwarrior.wordpress.com/2008/12/02/add-a-new-protocol-to-linux-kernel/

I inserted a new record to **linux/sock.h** header file:

```
#define AF_HTP      41  /* new HTP protocol family*/
#define AF_MAX      42  /* For now.. */
```

(it used to have only 41 protocol, AF_MAX = 41)

In my code, I did:

```
static struct net_proto_family htp_proto_family = {
    .family = AF_HTP,
    .create = htp_create_socket,
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
};

...

//in init_module
proto_register_status = proto_register(&htp_proto, 1);
```

And this is what I got by **dmesg** after failing to install module:

```
[  594.098672] protocol 41 >= NPROTO(41)
```

**My question:**
What should I do in this situation? Must I recompile the Linux kernel or there are some other workarounds?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This print comes from kernel code, not any driver. And as you can see, `41` is hard-coded... The kernel uses this const widely.
So yeah, in order to use a "new" AF you'll have to recompile Linux.

Another option is to reuse some other `AF_*` for your protocol - your kernel probably doesn't have all protocols loaded. so you can pick one of the unused "families" and use it. It'd work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it :)